# Java: Print out each number in an array without printing its an repeats of that number?

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to print out an array but only print out the distinct numbers in that array. 
For example: if the array has {5,5,3,6,3,5,2,1}
then it would print {5,3,6,2,1}

each time i do it either i only print the non repeating numbers, in this example {6,2,1} or i print them all. then i didnt it the way the assignment suggested

the assignment wants me to check the array before i place a value into it to see if its there first. If not then add it but if so dont.

now i just keep getting out of bounds error or it just prints everything.

any ideas on what i should do

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DistinctNums {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value;              
        int count = 0;  
        int[] distinct = new int[6];

        System.out.println("Enter Six Random Numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
        {
            value = input.nextInt(); //places users input into a variable 
        for (int j = 0; i < distinct.length; j++) {
            if (value != distinct[j]) //check to see if its in the array by making sure its not equal to anything in the array
            {
                distinct[count] = value; // if its not equal then place it in array
                count++; // increase counter for the array
            }
        }
        }

        // Displays the number of distinct numbers and the  
        // distinct numbers separated by exactly one space
        System.out.println("The number of distinct numbers is " + count);
        System.out.print("The distinct numbers are");
        for (int i = 0; i < distinct.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(distinct[i] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use Java collections, like `HashSet`?

Comment: @markspace im not sure. the chapter we are on focus are single dimensional arrays. they used list here and there but i didnt see any hashSet but at this point ill try anything

Comment: If you haven't learned it yet, you probably shouldn't try it.  (Has your instructor given you the lecture on cheating yet?)  You have to make your own set: consider breaking down the problem in a smaller idea: how to track whether a number is "in" a set of numbers (or in your case, how to track if a number has been printed yet).

Comment: @markspace yes, but he encourages us to seek help in forms if needed. He usually doesnt respond to emails very quickly or i would ask him for help

Comment: I don't want to rob you of your education here: find a set of numbers that doesn't work, then try executing the code by hand and try to find the bug that way.  One of your checks looks a little iffy.  (Google "hand execution" to learn about it.)  You can reduce the number of inputs to three to make this process shorter.

Comment: A good way to think of _an_ implementation is to do it by hand and then basically reproduce those steps on a computer. That leads to an algorithm which can usually do the task. No guarantees on efficiency, of course. :P

Comment: Just to point you in the right direction.. `if (value != distinct[j])` will up `count` every time an item on the `Array` isn't equal to `value`. This isn't what you want. What I would do is a have a `boolean` variable to determine if the element is unique or not and at the end of the second `for` loop, if it is unique, then add it to the `Array`

Comment: Just a hint not the complete answer. You have used `i` instead of `j` in inner loop. Analyse that, that could be the source of out of bound error.

Comment: @GBlodgett thank you for the suggestion. you were right, using a boolean to determine the unique number worked out. it took some time to work out the bugs but its all good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always remember - if you want a single copy of elements then you need to use **set**.
Set is a collection of distinct objects.

In Java, you have something called HashSet. And if you want the order to be maintained then use LinkedHashSet.

```
int [] intputArray = {5,5,3,6,3,5,2,1};
LinkedHashSet<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();

//add all the elements into set
for(int number:intputArray) {
    set.add(number);    
}
for(int element:set) {
    System.out.print(element+" ");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make this using help array with lenght of 10 if the order is not important.

```
    int [] intputArray = {5,5,3,6,3,5,2,1};
    int [] helpArray = new int[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < intputArray.length ; i++){
        helpArray[intputArray[i]]++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < helpArray.length ; i++){
        if(helpArray[i] > 0){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
```